# Redefine method body for method with Enum return type

Tags: java, enums, bytecode, javassist

I've written some javassist which redefines method bodies for some classes before they're being loaded, however I've run into a problem with one of the methods as it returns an enum which is defined in the class which is being modified, causing a can not find exception when it tries to compile the method.
Are there ways around this? I'll leave a simple example of code below.

```
 public class TEST {
    private float value;

    public TEST.CODE getCode() {
      return value < 1f ? TEST.CODE.ONE : TEST.CODE.TWO;
    }
   public enum CODE {
       ONE, TWO;
   }
}
```

With a Singleton providing override to the implementation.

```
public class SINGLETON {
     private static SINGLETON INSTANCE;

     private SINGLETON() {}

     public SINGLETON INSTANCE() {
       return INSTANCE != null ? INSTANCE : (INSTANCE = new SINGELTON());
     }

     public TEST.CODE getCode() {
         return TEST.CODE.ONE;
     }
}
```

When attempting to redefine getCode like so, javassist complains about compiling failure and not being able to find TEST$CODE

```
CtClass modified = pool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(inStream));
modified.getDeclaredMethod("getCode").setBody("{ return SINGLETON.INSTANCE().getCode(); }");
```

Comment: `{ return true; }` is not a valid method body for a method that returns an enum. It needs to be something like `{ return TEST.CODE.ONE; }`

Comment: Thanks, I quickly threw that example together, and I've updated it to be more thorough now.

Comment: The idea of having a code generator that works like a compiler is tempting, but doesn’t play well with load-time Instrumentation. Generating byte code with a library like ASM might be harder in the beginning, but pays off soon, as such things like load-time Instrumentation are no challenge anymore.